# Almost everywhere convergence of a bounded sequence in $H_0^1(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence, almost-everywhere

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a smooth domain with bounded complement (e.g. $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^N \setminus \overline{B(0;1)}$), and $(u_n)$ be a bounded sequence in $H^1_0(\Omega) = W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$.

Since $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is a reflexive Banach space, weak compactness implies the existence of a subsequence $(u_{n_k})$ and a function $u_0 \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that $u_{n_k} \rightharpoonup u_0$ weakly in $H^1_0(\Omega)$. May I assume that (going if necessary to a subsequence, which I still denote by $(u_{n_k})$) that $u_{n_k} \rightarrow u_0$ almost everywhere on $\Omega$?

According to the Rellich theorem, for $\omega \Subset \Omega$ (compactly embedded), the embedding
$$H_0^1(\omega) \subset L^p(\omega)$$
is compact for all $1 \leq p < 2^*$. Hence, we may assume that $u_n \rightarrow u_0$ in $L^p(\omega)$, with $1 \leq p < 2^*$. Thus, by some theorem, there exists a subsequence (still denoted $(u_n)$) such that $u_n \rightarrow u_0$ almost everywhere on $\Omega$. Can we (as proposed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152528/does-weak-convergence-in-sobolev-spaces-imply-pointwise-convergence)) exhaust $\Omega$ by balls of increasing radius and conclude that $u_n \rightarrow u_0$ almost everywhere on $\Omega$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post your version of Rellich's theorem? There is a version that states that bounded sequences in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ converge strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$. Thus up to a subsequence pointwise a.e.

Comment: Rellich theorem: If $\vert \Omega \vert < \infty$, the embeddings $H_0^1(\Omega) \subset L^p(\Omega)$, $1 \leq p < 2^*$, are compact. Here, $\Omega$ is a smooth domain with bounded complement, meaning $\vert \Omega \vert = \infty$. Hence the Rellich theorem does not apply directly.

Comment: What about the assumptions of bounded complement? I think in your example domain one could use the reflection $x/|x|$ (or $x/|x|^2$). Have you tried this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the following:

Fix the sequence $u_n\to u$ weakly in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ as you suggest in your post. Define $\Omega_k:=\Omega\cap B(0,k)$. Then each $\Omega_k$ is compact and hence we could consider to use Rellich theorem.

But before we do that, let me point out that the boundary $\partial \Omega_k$ may not be smooth, actually it can even be pretty bad, even if $\partial\Omega$ is smooth... So the Rellich theorem won't work here directly.

But now, let me wave my hand and assume that $\partial \Omega_k$ is good enough so that we could use Rellich on it. Take $k=1$, then by Rellich, from the sequence $u_n$ we could extract a future subsequence, call it $u_{n_{(1)}}$, such that $u_{n_{(1)}}\to u$ at least in $L^1(\Omega_1)$ strongly. Hence you know that $u_{n_{(1)}}\to u$ a.e. (subject to a subsequence of course) in $\Omega_1$. Continuous on this method, by diagonalization argument, you could obtain a subsequence, still denote as $u_n$, such that $u_n\to u$ weakly and $u_n\to u$ a.e. on $\Omega$. But be careful that you can not conclude $u_n\to u$ strongly in $L^1(\Omega)$, you could only say that $u_n\to u$ in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$

Having said that, now let's consider what if $\partial \Omega_k$ is not smooth, or, not a extension domain. Here is one thing can probably rescue us. On [Leoni](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847686)'s book, exercise 11.17, he gives the following statement:

*The space $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is compact embedded in $L^q(\Omega)$ when $q<p$ and $\Omega$ is finite.*

In our argument, of course $\Omega_k$ is finite for each $k$ and hence we at least can have $H_0^1(\Omega_k)$ is compact embedded in $L^1(\Omega_K)$ and hence we are good.

However, here I must warn you that I only see this statement in Leoni's book but no-where-else. (On Adam's book, it has the inverse statement, i.e., compact embedding implies that $\Omega$ is finite.) I also receive concern from my friend that this exercise is wrong but they are not sure... Anyhow, at least I have a prove of this exercise by myself but maybe you could work out a proof yourself too...

Comment: In the book of Alt (Funktionalanalysis, german) no boundary regularity is needed to obtain the compact embedding $H^1_0(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)$ (as long as $\Omega$ is bounded). Without the subscript zero Lipschitz regularity is needed. However, there $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is defined as the closure of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ with respect to the $H^1$ norm.

Comment: What about the assumption of bounded complement? This is not used in your approach. Any idea on how to use this? If the doamin is really $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \overline B_1(0)$. A reflection might help

Comment: I confirm: If $N > 2$, the embeddings $H^1(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^p(\Omega)$ for $1 \leq p < 2^*$ are compact provided that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is a bounded domain with Lipschitz boundary. The embeddings are still compact for $H_0^1(\Omega)$-spaces on arbitrary bounded domains $\Omega$. This can be found in Adams' book. The geometry of $\Omega$ should not matter. Hence we have no guarantee that the $\Omega_k$ will have Lipschitz boundary. Anyway, thanks to both of you for your help.

Comment: We could extend the bounded sequence $(u_n) \subset H_0^1(\Omega)$ by zero on the bounded complement of $\Omega$. Let $(\widetilde{u}_n) \subset H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ be such an extension. How can we be sure that if $u_n \rightharpoonup u_0$ in $H^1_0(\Omega)$, then $\widetilde{u}_n \rightarrow \widetilde{u}_0$ almost everywhere (hence $u_n \rightarrow u_0$ a.e. on $\Omega$), where $\widetilde{u}_0$ is the extension by zero of $u_0$ ?

Comment: Sure, $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ will be compact embedded in $L^{p^*}(\Omega)$ as long as $\Omega$ is bounded, but no boundary condition is needed whatsoever. However, in your setting that $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ only, so for $\Omega_k\subset \Omega$, we never know $u\in H_0^1(\Omega_k)$ or not, it probably in $H^1(\Omega_k)$. Hence, boundary of $\Omega_k$ is still important. But, as I said in my answer, we only need $L^1$ convergence to obtain a.e. convergence, so my prove should work.

Comment: Moreover, I thought your $\Omega$ is just a smooth domain with bounded complement, and $R^N\setminus B(0,1)$ is only an example. But if your domain is just $R^N\setminus B(0,1)$, then of course $\Omega_k$ has smooth boundary as well and usual embedding will works fine.

Comment: If the embedding $H^1(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^p(\Omega)$ is compact when $1 \leq p < 2$ and $\Omega$ is of finite measure (as stated in Leoni's book), then your proof should indeed work. However, I'm not yet convinced by Leoni's statement. I'll have to work on that. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.