# Weak convergence and almost everywhere convergence on $H_0^1({\mathbb{R}}^N)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence, almost-everywhere

I am seeking a clarification to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/152528/859950) question on almost convergence in Sobolev spaces. The essence of the answer there was to prove that if a sequence $(u_n) \rightharpoonup u$ in $H_0^1({\mathbb{R}}^N)$, then upto subsequences, $u_k(x) \rightharpoonup u(x)$ a.e on $\mathbb{R}^N$. Since the embedding theorems cannot be directly applied for $\mathbb{R}^N$, the approach was to consider open balls of increasing radii and somehow prove the statement. This method was also given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1012555/859950).

I'm not sure if this method or the reasoning behind it works. If we define $\Omega_k = B(0,k)$, we can find, for each $k$, a subsequence $\{u_n^{(k)}\}_n$ that converges a.e to $u(x)$ on $\Omega_k$, but it is unclear how one would take the limit.

More precisely, for any $\varepsilon >0 $, let $N_k$ be an integer such that $n > N_k \implies  |u_n^{(k)}(x) - u(x)| < \varepsilon, \text{ a.e on } \Omega_k$. To prove the statement, we need to find a subsequence $(u_n)$ such that there always exists an $N$ with the property $n > N \implies |u_n(x) - u(x)| < \varepsilon$. I don't see how one can prove that, since $N$ can "escape to infinity". Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use a "**diagonal argument**".

First, you extract a subsequence $\{ u_n^{(1)} \}$ from $\{ u_n \}$ such that $u_n^{(1)}$ converges pointwise inside $\Omega_1$.

Then, **from this subsequence**, you extract $\{ u_n^{(2)} \}$ which converges pointwise inside $\Omega_2$.

Iteratively, you defined the subsequence $\{ u_n^{(k+1)} \}$ as being extracted from $\{ u_n^{(k)} \}$ and converging pointwise inside $\Omega_{k+1}$.

Eventually, you define, say, $v_n := u_n^{(n)}$ (hence the "diagonal" name for the argument).

Now take any $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$. For $k$ large enough $x \in \Omega_k$. And for $n \geq k$ large enough, $v_n$ is an element of a subsequence of $\{ u^{(k)} \}$, so $v_n(x) \to u(x)$.

Comment: Can you please clarify how one can always extract $u_n^{(2)}$ from $u_n^{(1)}$? I don't intuitively see how a sequence converging on a smaller domain necessarily has a convergent subsequence on a larger domain. (I'm an undergrad and this is my first contact with Functional analysis, so you may need to excuse the pedantry :) )

Comment: Take a bounded sequence in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$. For any compact $K \subset \mathbb{R}^N$, by the Rellich-Kondrachov compact embedding theorem, it has a subsequence strongly converging in $L^1(K)$. In particular, this subsequence converges pointwise almost everwhere in $K$.

Comment: Now once you have constructed $u_n^{(1)}$ to converge pointwise in $\Omega_1$, this subsequence is still bounded in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$. So you can apply the previous comment to extract from itself a subsequence designed for $\Omega_2$. And so on.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification.